# putExtra data defined in programatically created ImageButtons only sees last value?

Tags: android, android-intent, imagebutton

I have programatically defined a set of imagebuttons in a for loop. For each button, I defined its setOnClickListener function which will put some data in the intent and then switch activity. However, it seems like no matter which button I clicked on, the extra data retrieved is set the the last value int he for loop. See code here:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   <...>

        RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rlayout);

        for (int i=1; i<=maxMapLoc; i++ ) {
            mapLocation = i;
            ImageButton btnMapLoc = new ImageButton(FirstActivity.this);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams vp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            btnMapLoc.setLayoutParams(vp);
            btnMapLoc.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            btnMapLoc.requestLayout();
            String imgName = "map_loc_" + mapLocation;                
            int id = getResources().getIdentifier(imgName,"drawable",getPackageName());
            btnMapLoc.setImageResource(id);
            int imgMapLoc = 2000 + mapLocation;
            btnMapLoc.setId(imgMapLoc);
            rl.addView(btnMapLoc, vp);

            btnMapLoc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("MapLocation", mapLocation);

                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            });
```

Any idea what I did wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: You might want to print out the button's ID in the onClick method to make sure the button you click is in fact the button you are expecting to be triggered. So, the first button should have an ID for '2001' and the second button should have an id of '2002'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a tag to your button with the current mapLocation value.

```
btnMapLoc.setTag(i);
...

// In onClick
    intent.putExtra("MapLocation", v.getTag());
    ...
```

The reason why you only get the last value of `mapLocation` is that the code inside your onClick() is run when the user pushes a button.  In other words your are querying `mapLocation` long after the loop built your buttons.  You need to create a reference to the current `mapLocation` in each loop iteration, like with the tag feature.

Comment: Thanks. The get- and setTag functions did the trick! I was not aware that the code inside the onClick() is "sourced" at run time. I thought the implementation of calls inside are "copied and stored" in each instance of the view as they were created so the dynamic assignments would have been recorded in memory...